# how to parse the thymeleaf object to js function argument

Tags: angularjs, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf th: each to iterate a list. On each iteration, it will call an angularjs function. But the item object what I get inside the function is undefined.
how to parse the thymeleaf object to js function argument.

```
<div th:each="item : ${items}" >
     <div ng-show="showParameter(${item})">
         <label>Hello</label>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: How (and why) are you combining Thymeleaf and AngularJs?

Comment: Because I want to hide the child div based on server callback inside that function.

Comment: So you prerender your AngularJs templates on the server with Thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes. I'm using thymeleaf for dynamically constructing ng-models.

Comment: This seems... questionable... Can you provide some information on how the templates from the server "get into" the AngularJs app?

Comment: My best guess so far: since `${item}` is not within a thymeleaf expression like `th:text` it does not get recognized by thymeleaf. In that case your templates should have "${item}" hardcoded into them.

Comment: And why don't you just use `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Basically, this is a Spring MVC app with Thymeleaf+Angularjs. the template will load using the spring controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198531/discussion-between-scorpioo590-and-boycod3).